Azure Virtual Machine - Programatically Start / Stop Machine
I've tried to reference this as best I can, but I can't seem to find anything immediately obvious in either Azure SDK documentation or various examples in their repositories.
Essentially, I would like to be able to programmatically start / stop an Azure VM, perhaps from a simple Python script or Go lang ... does anyone know if this is this possible with any of the APIs in their SDK?
If yes, where could I find any references to achieve this?


Azure Virtual Machine - Programatically Start / Stop Machine

Here is the Python code to stop/start the Azure VM
    from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
    from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
    from azure.mgmt.compute.models import VirtualMachine
    
    # Azure subscription ID
    subscription_id = 'subscription_id'
    
    # Resource group name and VM name
    resource_group_name = 'Venkat'
    vm_name = 'venkat-vm'
    
    # Initialize Azure credentials
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    
    # Initialize ComputeManagementClient
    compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
    
    # Stop the VM
    async_vm_stop = compute_client.virtual_machines.begin_power_off(resource_group_name, vm_name)
    async_vm_stop.wait()
    
    print(f"The VM {vm_name} has been stopped.")

Start the VM
  async_vm_start = compute_client.virtual_machines.begin_start(resource_group_name, vm_name)
  async_vm_start.wait()
  
  print(f"The VM {vm_name} has been started.")

After running the code, the virtual machine has successfully stopped.



Cool, appreciate this enormously. Do you know what package I need to install, is this azure-sdk for python?

I assume https://pypi.org/project/azure/

Install azure.mgmt.compute if it is not already installed.                                        pip install azure.mgmt.compute,
pip install azure.identity

Hope this helps to resolve your query

That helps, one more question - and apologies to keep shifting the goalposts. Is there an equivalent Go SDK to do this?

@NaveenSharma I haven't yet verified the solution as yet, I did ask if there was a Go lang SDK in the Q.

Hi @MichealJ.Roberts, refer this link  for Go lang compute SDK's
